# how to hide/show toolbar and status bar when web view scroll in android at the same time

Tags: android

my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

toolbar can hide/show when web view scrolls now, I would like to hide or show the status bar at the same time

what can i do? thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend webview using this class Android-ObservableScrollView
   https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView
2. Add event onscroll at webview in activity class:

   ```
   mWebView.setOnScrollChangedCallback(new AdvancedWebView.OnScrollChangedCallback() {
       public void onScroll(int l, int t) {

           float newY = mWebView.getScrollY();
           if (newY >= yPosition) {
               //hide layout
               hideToolbar();
           } else {
               //show toolbar
               showToolbar();
           }
           yPosition = newY;
       }
   });
   ```
3. Toolbar show hide:

   ```
   private void hideToolbar() {
       getSupportActionBar().hide();
   }

   private void showToolbar() {
       getSupportActionBar().show();
   }
   ```

Using WebView inside NestedScrollView is too much lag and not supported zoom feature.

Comment: thanks, but the status bar  cannot hide/show at the same time

Comment: where is in your view the status bar? I don't understand, can you give screenshot or link referance?